# Passing a default parameter to a Rails 3 route makes it fail to match the route in the controller test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-routing

I'm upgrading an old application for a non-profit, and I've having issues with some routes and controller tests on Rails 3.0.20 (Rails 2 -> 3 is the first of many upgrades I need to make :( )

This is my route definition:

```
match "new/tribes" => "news#tribes",
  as: "en_news_tribes",  
  defaults: {
    page_slug: 'tribes',
    language_id: 3,
    section_id: 4
  }
```

The idea is that when the controller is called the parameters will include the default values for page_slug, language_id and section_id

In my controller test (TestUnit based) the action is invoked like this:

```
get :tribes, { section_id: 4, language_id: 4, tribe_id: @loc_tribe.tribe.id }
```

But this produces this routing exception:

```
ActionController::RoutingError: No route matches {:section_id=>4, :language_id=>3, :tribe_id=>1, :controller=>"news", :action=>"tribes"}
```

Only if I specify all the default parameters does it find a route (and the test passes):

```
get :tribes, { section_id: 4, language_id: 4, tribe_id: @loc_tribe.tribe.id, page_slug: 'tribes' }
```

If the parameters I pass don't match the default parameter values specified in `config/routes.rb` it doesn't find the route.

i.e. This doesn't work:

```
get :tribes, { section_id: 4, language_id: 4, tribe_id: @loc_tribe.tribe.id, page_slug: 'Abc123' }
```

So it seems like these default values are in fact behaving as routing constraints?

I hope someone can help! I am at the start of a long road in getting this application to Rails 5 ;)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `default_url_options`. I think it may help you.

```
class AppplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # ...

  protected

  def default_url_options
    { page_slug: 'tribes', language_id: 3, section_id: 4 }
  end
end
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply.

Unfortunately this won't work for us in this application. The example I gave above is simplified. In reality there are multiple routes generated with different I18n'ed path names and different language IDs, so it's not like these defaults can be fixed.

In production they need to be set via the path that gets hit, and passed to the controller.

Comment: How about `{ page_slug: params[:page_slug], language_id: params[:language_id], section_id: params[:section_id] }`